# Is OpenCV compiled from sources faster than OpenCV installed using pip

Tags: python, opencv, unix, opencv3.0

Apologies if the question is not relevant to this forum, but i have read comments around turning certain flags on/off during compiling from source which makes opencv Faster.

Is there some truth to this

Comment: Are you sure that version is consistent for both of them ?

Comment: Yes, it is true. Some flags enable/disable parallelism, some enable/disable use of GPU, some enable/disable optimisations (SIMD and others), some permit faster/less accurate maths and so on... I mean it is true that some flags will make OpenCV faster, some will also make it slower so it is not necessarily true that compiling from source is faster - it could be slower if you set the flags sub-optimally (geek-speak for *"badly"*)

Comment: @ZdaR , yes I am talking about both opencv's belonging to same version